# Javascript string as variable

Tags: javascript, html

ok i have tried eval and window with no success:

I receive part of a radio button name that i then want to use to set that button to checked, below is the function, it works if i replace the square brackets with the name of one of the products so i know the problem is with the stuff in the square brackets, please help, how do i do this?

```
function load_rights(product)
{
document.form.window[product+"_radio_selection"][0].checked = true;
//also tried - var tempstr = eval(product+'_radio_selection');
//           - document.form.tempstr[0].checked = true;

}
```

In PHP the radio button is generated:

```php
echo "<input name='".$value."_radio_selection' type='radio' value='yes' />"
ehco "<input name='".$value."_radio_selection' type='radio' checked='checked' value='no' />"
```

You cnt use the element by id - it does not work with radio buttons, trust me, i spent a whole day the other day learning that.

If i try the element id and add id tags to the html i get a null error, if i use the window i get a null error, but if i put in one of the products like document.form.Admin_radio_selection[0].checked = true; IT WORKs, arrr so annoying ..

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: what is the value of product?

Comment: View source in the browser and post the resulting HTML.

Comment: @David: Please update your question when you are providing additional information. (That is much more convenient to read)

Comment: i cnt post the html through source view - it is echoed via php/ajax into a div

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates using document.getElementById with a radio button:  http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/V25PU/

Comment: Also, remember that element IDs need to be **unique**

Comment: Have you added the requisite ID's? If you have, can you update your question to reflect what you really have right now? If not, then this question will be closed as too localized, as in "I have a problem but I'm not going to describe everything to you, please guess what the problem is".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a pure Javascript solution, I'd say your best bet is to put IDs on the radio inputs.  Then you can use `document.getElementById` to get a handle to the element.

```
<input type="radio" id="foo_radio_selection" value="" />Foo<br />
<input type="radio" id="bar_radio_selection" value="" />Bar<br />

function load_rights(product) {
   document.getElementById(product+'_radio_selection').checked = true;   
}

load_rights('bar');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/zkbwL/2/)

Comment: says its null, i seem to remember you cnt use getElementById with radio buttons

Comment: If you're still getting null, then the ID of the radio button HTML element doesn't match what you're passing to getElementById.  Additionally, you can use getElementById with *anything* that has an ID :)

Answer (score 1):

you could try considering [jquery](http://jqueryui.com/) 
`$(':checkbox').filter('name=somename').attr('checked',true);`

this is the simplest way of doing this.

or you could also say `document.form[0].<<checkboxname>>.checked=true`

Comment: did you try this `document.form[0].<<checkboxname>>.checked=true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the element using its ID with [getElementById()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp):

```
var e = document.getElementById(product+"_radio_selection");
e.checked = true;
```

In order to let this work you need to add IDs to your radio buttons, as shown by [Mark Biek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025859/javascript-string-as-variable/7025899#7025899) already.

Comment: says its null, i seem to remember you cnt use getElementById with radio buttons

Comment: It probably says null because your markup, as it stands, doesn't have ID attributes.  You'll need to add them.

Comment: i did, still null, also null if i use window[] (but if i hard code it like document.form.Admin_radio_selection[0].checked = true; works for that product..

Comment: Mark shows a _working_ example in jsFiddle, so I am afraid you are missing something else

Comment: In your example code, there are no `id="myid_here"` attributes added, so indeed it does not work. Try adding them, and make sure they are unique.